# Eckart–Young–Mirsky theorem for $n \gg m$

Tags: pca, svd, consistency, matrix-decomposition

It has been proven that the best reconstruction error in the $k$ rank matrix estimation problem in terms of Frobenius or $L2$ norm is given by the $k$-truncated SVD as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation). I've read in multiple papers and e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_PCA) that PCA loses consistency for $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ as $n \gg m$ and alternatives have been proposed as in the link I've provided (Sparse PCA).

Does that mean that the Eckart–Young–Mirsky theorem doesn't hold for $n \gg m$ or that the Frobenius or $L2$ norm don't capture this inconsistency and that e.g. sparse PCA has the same or worse norm but better consistency?